# How to read and parse specific integer value form a text file and add it to listbox in c#?

Tags: c#, parsing, listbox, text-files

i'd like to know how to read and parse specific integer value form a text file and add it to listbox in c#. For example I have a text file MyText.txt like this:

```
<>
101
192
-
399
~
99
128
-
366
~
101
192
-
403
~
```

And I want to parse the integer value between '-' and '~' and add each one of it to items in list box for example:

```
#listBox1
399
366
403
```

Notice that each line of value separated by Carriage Return and Line Feed. And by the way, it is a data transmitted through RS-232 Serial Communication from microcontroller. Sorry, I'm just new in c# programming. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? And is this winforms, asp.net, WPF?

Comment: Read line by line. When you find a - mark as the beginning. When you hit ~ mark as the end. The numbers between - and ~ you put them in a list. When you hit the end ~ you take the numbers from the list and put them in the list box.

Comment: Yes. I've done "trial and error" effort using int.Parse and Split with a button, no build error but I got an exception handle when debugged. And it is Windows Forms Application.

Comment: I'm now using Visual C# 2008. By logically, I know how to do it. The problem is I'm struggling how to interpret it in C# syntax.

Comment: @Michael you might want to identify which particular parts you can't do in C#, and then solve those problems individually. I'm sure you will find SO questions and answers for every step of the process.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do it with LINQ:

```
        bool keep = false;
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(
            File.ReadLines("MyText.txt")
            .Where(l =>
            {
                if (l == "-") keep = true;
                else if (l == "~") keep = false;
                else return keep;
                return false;
            })
            .ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use regular expressions like so:

```
var s = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(stringtomatch,@"(?<=-\s*)[0-9]+\b(?=\s*~)");
```

The regex basically looks for a number. It then checks the characters behind, looks for an optional whitespace and a dash (-). then it matches all the numbers until it encounters another non-word character. it checks for an optional whitespace and then a required ~ (dunno what that's called). Also, it only returns the number (not the whitespace and symbols).

So basically this method returns a list of matches. you could then use it like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.Count; i++)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(s[i]);
}
```

EDIT:

typo in the regex and updated the loop (for some reason, foreach doesn't work with the MatchCollection).

you can try running this test script:

```
var stringtomatch = " asdjasdk jh kjh asd\n-\n123123\n~\nasdasd";
var s = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(stringtomatch,@"(?<=-\s*)[0-9]+\b(?=\s*~)");
Console.WriteLine(stringtomatch);
for (int i = 0; i < s.Count; i++)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(s[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works just fine. By the way, how to convert the result into integer?

Comment: you can use int.TryParse() or int.Parse()

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
List<Int32> values = new List<Int32>();
bool open = false;
String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
foreach(String line in lines)
{
  if( (!open) && (line == "-") )
  {
    open = true;
  }
  else if( (open) && (line == "~") )
  {
    open = false;
  }
  else if(open)
  {
    Int32 v;
    if(Int32.TryParse(line, out v)) 
    {
      values.Add(v);
    }
  }
}
Listbox.Items.AddRange(values);
```

This is a easy piece of code with reading a file, converting to integer (although you could stay with strings) and handling lists. You should start with some basic .NET/C# tutorials.

**Edit**: To add the values to the listbox you can switch to `values.ForEach(v => listbox.Items.Add(v.ToString())` if you use .NET 3.5. Otherwise make a foreach yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I got these errors when I build your code:
1. Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'char' (is there an alternative operator in C#?)

Comment: You cannot use single quotes for strings in C# - single quotes denote a char type. A string is an array of char types. ie. str[0] will get the first letter of the string as a char.

Comment: (Sorry, got separated. I don't know that I should use Shift+Enter to change line in "Add Comment" text box)
2. The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection.AddRange(System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection)' has some invalid arguments. (I'm kinda not understand this part)
3. Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection'(I'm lost this one).